# load another package's data in local R package

Tags: r

I am trying to create an R package that calls some functions from the `signatureSearch` R package for e.g. `signatureSearch::gess_lincs` and `signatureSearch::addGESSannot` functions. This is the header of my script in my R package script `lincs_connectivity.R`:

```
#' Function: Connectivity Analysis using LINCS
#'
#' @import AnnotationDbi
#' @import org.Hs.eg.db
#' @import signatureSearch
#' @import signatureSearchData
#' @import dplyr

lincs_connectivity <- function(){
...
}
```

This way my script is successfully able to call the functions that belong to the `signatureSearch` package. However, there is a line within the `signatureSearch::addGESSannot` function that loads the `clue_moa_list` data from the `signatureSearch` package like this:

```
data("clue_moa_list", envir = environment())
res <- addMOA(res, cmp_name_col, clue_moa_list)
```

Here is the corresponding code: https://github.com/girke-lab/signatureSearch/blob/devel/R/utilities.R#L768-L769

Even though the signatureSearch functions are successfully being called in my R package, it is unable to load the corresponding data available within the signatureSearch package and gives me the following error:

```
Error in addMOA(res, cmp_name_col, clue_moa_list) : 
  object 'clue_moa_list' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In data("clue_moa_list", envir = environment()) :
  data set 'clue_moa_list' not found
```

As this line is within the built-in function, how do I circumvent this error? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!